# How can I get specific document data from firestore querysnapshot?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I got a querysnapshot in a function.
And want to bring the whole querysnapshot to another function (functionTwo).
In functionTwo, I want to get a specific document in the querysnapshot **WITHOUT** forEach. The specific doc can be changed by different cases.

```
ref_serial_setting.get()
    .then(querysnapshot => {
      return functionTwo(querysnapshot)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err)
    })


let functionTwo = (querysnapshot) => {
  // getting value

  const dataKey_1 = "dataKey_1"

  // Tried 1
  const value = querysnapshot.doc(dataKey_1).data()

  // Tried 2
  const value = querysnapshot.document(dataKey_1).data()

  // Tried 3 (Put 'data_name': dataKey_1 in that doc)
  const value = querysnapshot.where('data_name', '==', dataKey_1).data()
}
```

The result are all these trying are not a function.

How can I get specific document data from querysnapshot??

or

Is there any easy method to change the querysnapshot to JSON?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get an array of the document snapshots by using the `docs` property of a `QuerySnapshot`. After that you'll have to loop through getting the data of the doc snapshots looking for your doc.

```
const docSnapshots = querysnapshot.docs;

for (var i in docSnapshots) {
    const doc = docSnapshots[i].data();

    // Check for your document data here and break when you find it
}
```

**Or** if you don't actually need the full `QuerySnapshot`, you can apply the filter using the `where` function **before** calling `get` on the query object:

```
const dataKey_1 = "dataKey_1";    
const initialQuery = ref_serial_setting;
const filteredQuery = initialQuery.where('data_name', '==', dataKey_1);

filteredQuery.get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        // If your data is unique in that document collection, you should
        // get a query snapshot containing only 1 document snapshot here
    })

    .catch(error => {
        // Catch errors
    });
```

Comment: All the info on `QuerySnapshot` objects is available [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I know the exact doc name in the querysnapshot. Do I still need to loop through the "docSnapshots" to get the data inside? // 

I need the full QuerySnapshot because I have some other function to get the exact doc name from other places.

Comment: I see, unfortunately if you need the full `QuerySnapshot` then you're going to have to run through each doc snapshot and search for the name. It's just the nature of how Firestore wraps data in returned queries. Sorry I can't give you the answer you want to hear, but at the moment, `QuerySnapshots` don't support search or filter methods.

Answer (score 1):

Theres an easy way to do this, each `QuerySnapshot` has a property `docs` which returns an array of `QueryDocumentSnapshots`. See [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) documentation.

```
let citiesRef = db.collection('cities');
let query = citiesRef.where('capital', '==', true).get().then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.docs[0]; // => returns first document
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let citiesRef = db.collection('cities');
let query = citiesRef.where('capital', '==', true).get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      console.log('No matching documents.');
      return;
    }  

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });
```

from https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: Thanks, this forEach worked really well for me! The other answers about loops I couldn't get to work.

Answer (score 0):

#### you can use this code :

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "collectionNaame"));
const docSnapshots = querySnapshot.docs;
for (var i in docSnapshots) {
console.log(i)
const doc = docSnapshots[i].data();
console.log(doc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
db.doc(<<ref>>).get()
```

this returns a promise

[here ]: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document is the link to the docs