# Trying to load all firestore documents in Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can request a specific document in a collection successfully. But I need to be able to query all documents, as Firestore (unlike the realtime database) doesn't support exporting.

I know the following is not possible, but surely there is some way to export a whole collection?

```
router.get('/firebase', function (req, res) {
    var admin = require('firebase-admin');
    const firebaseConfig = require('../firebaseConfig.json');

    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(firebaseConfig),
        databaseURL: 'https://***.firebaseio.com'
    });

    let db = admin.firestore();
    let cityRef = db.collection('marketing').doc('*');
    let getDoc = cityRef.get()
        .then(doc => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
                console.log('No such document!');
            } else {
                console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error getting document', err);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A refactored version of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52101894/12379739) by [Doug Stevenson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126/doug-stevenson)

```
router.get('/firebase', async function (req, res) {
    var admin = require('firebase-admin');
    const firebaseConfig = require('../firebaseConfig.json');

    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(firebaseConfig),
        databaseURL: 'https://gundies.firebaseio.com'
    });

    let db = admin.firestore();

    const snapshot = await db.collection("marketing").get();

    const docs = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
```

The variable 'docs' will hold all your data!

Comment: I like this async code, very clean, I will use this instead of my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`db.collection('marketing').doc('*')` is not the correct syntax.  There are no document wildcards in Firestore queries.  Just use `db.collection('marketing').get()` to get a QuerySnapshot with all the documents in the collection.

It works just like you see in the [documentation for queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries), except you are not specifying any filter to limit the result set.

Answer (score 1):

As per Doug's answer, not loading a `.doc()` allowed me to get all the records. I had tried this earlier but the console.log was quite difficult to read. Adding a forEach from this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57448448/3554127)
helped out.

```
router.get('/firebase', function (req, res) {
    var admin = require('firebase-admin');
    const firebaseConfig = require('../firebaseConfig.json');

    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(firebaseConfig),
        databaseURL: 'https://***.firebaseio.com'
    });

    let db = admin.firestore();

    db.collection('marketing').get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error getting document', err);
        });
});
```