# I am trying to use a field from the collection 'profile' say 'username' to filter the records from the main collection 'orders'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to achieve this?
i have tried to assign the entry to a local variable but it doesn't work with crudmethods.

```
getData() async {
    String userId = 'userId';
    Firestore.instance.collection('user').document(userId).snapshots();
    var snapshot;
    var userDocument = snapshot.data;
    String _myAddress = userDocument["address"];
    return Firestore.instance
        .collection('letters')
        .where("source Box", isEqualTo: _myAddress)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

Comment: People will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to use a document in the query of another document.
For this, you need to create a reference for one collection and use it in another one.

The below code is an example that you can give it a try adapting further for your case, but that I believe should help you.

```
// Create references to the profile and orders collections
var profilesRef = db.collection("profile");
var ordersRef = db.collection("orders");

// Create a query against the collection.
var query = ordersRef.where("username", "==", ).doc("username").get();
```

In the documentation [Perform simple and compound queries in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries), there is more information and example of queries that should help you.

In addition to that, this below post from the Community can provide you some insights on how to achieve this type of query as well.

- [How can I get specific document data from firestore querysnapshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692218/how-can-i-get-specific-document-data-from-firestore-querysnapshot)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this on flutter. Do you have any insight.

Comment: Hi @JustinWaweru for Flutter, I would recommend you to take a look at this article [here](https://medium.com/@kfarsoft/deeping-firestore-queries-with-flutter-2210fd3b49e1) and this other [Community question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937864/firestore-queries-on-flutter), where there are some useful cases that you can check, of queries with Flutter.